# adding an identity matrix will increase the rank?

Tags: linear-algebra

If $rank(A)=r, A \in R^{n\times n}$, $A$ is non-symmetric and I want to find $rank(A+cI), c \in R /\{0\}$:

$$rank(A+cI) \le rank(A) + rank(cI) = r + n$$

My question is there a condition where $rank(A+cI) = r$? In other words, is it always true that adding an identity matrix will increase the rank?

Comment: It is not always true. Consider $\pmatrix{-1&1\\ 0&-1}+I_2$ for instance.

Comment: Do you know what eigenvalues are?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

A similar inequality tells you that $\text{rank}(cI) \le \text{rank}(A+cI) + \text{rank}(-A)$, or $\text{rank}(A+cI) \ge \text{rank}(cI) - \text{rank}(-A) = n-r$.

So when $r < \frac n2$, we are guaranteed to increase the rank.

When $r \ge \frac n2$, it's possible for the rank to stay the same. For example, if $A$ is a diagonal matrix with the entries $$\underbrace{0, 0, \dots, 0}_{n/2}, \underbrace{-c, -c, \dots, -c}_{n/2}$$ on the diagonal, then $A+cI$ will have the entries $$\underbrace{c,c,\dots,c}_{n/2}, \underbrace{0, 0, \dots, 0}_{n/2}$$ on the diagonal, and both $A$ and $A+cI$ have rank $\frac n2$.

In general, you are just asking for $0$ and $-c$ to be eigenvalues with the same geometric multiplicity (or, in the case $r=n$, for neither of them to be eigenvalues).